# SQL not returning when executed on top of a large data set

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, performance

I have below sql which is getting stuck in oracle database for more than 2 hours. This stuck happens only when it is executed via the C++ application. Interestingly, at the same time when it was stuck I can execute it through sql developer manually and it returns within seconds. My table has millions of rows and about 100 columns. Can someone please point out how can I overcome this issue?

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE  
     INNER JOIN ( (select max(concat(DATE ,concat('',to_char(INDEX, '0000000000')))) AS UNIQUE_ID 
            from MY_TABLE 
            WHERE ((DATE < '2018/01/29') 
            OR (DATE = '2018/01/29' AND INDEX <= 100000))
            AND EXISTS ( select ID 
                         from MY_TABLE 
                         where DATE = '2018/01/29'
                         AND INDEX > 100000 
                         AND LATEST =1) 
           group by ID ) SELECTED_SET ) 
      ON SELECTED_SET.UNIQUE_ID = concat(DATE, concat('',to_char(INDEX, '0000000000'))) 
 WHERE (FIELD_1 = 1 AND FIELD_2 = 1 AND FIELD_3='SomeString');
```

UPDATE:

**db file sequential read** is present on the session.

```
SELECT p3, count(*) FROM v$session_wait WHERE event='db file sequential read' GROUP BY p3;
```

.......................................
| P3      | COUNT(*)   |
.......................................
| 1       | 2         |
.......................................

Comment: Can you confirm that the query is executed when called from your application code? This clearly needs some debugging stepping through your code and see what's actually going on.

Comment: Yes. the application is halted and is waiting for sql to be returned. In DB, the session from the code is visible with the sql and it is shown as buffer busy wait.

Comment: Is your query really querying the same table three times? Or is that just an artefact of the way you redacted your code?

Answer (score 0):

> "I can execute it through sql developer manually and it returns within seconds"

Clearly the problem is not intrinsic to the query. So it must be a problem with your application.

Perhaps you have a slow network connection between your C++ application and the database. To check this you should talk to your network admin team. They are likely to be resistant to the suggestion that the network is the problem. So you may need to download and install Wireshark, and investigate it yourself.

Or your C++ is just very inefficient in handling the data. Is the code instrumented? Do you know what it's been doing for those two hours?

---

> "the session is shown as 'buffer busy wait'"

Buffer busy waits indicate contention for blocks between sessions. If your application has many sessions running this query then you may have a problem. Buffer busy waits can indicate that there are sessions waiting on a full table scan to complete; but as the query returned results when you ran it in SQL Developer I think we can discount this. Perhaps there are other sessions updating `MY_TABLE`. How many sessions are reading or writing to it?

Also, what is the output of this query?

```
SELECT p3, count(*) 
  FROM v$session_wait 
  WHERE event='buffer busy wait'
 GROUP BY p3
;
```

Comment: Code is just waiting for the sql to return. When checked in DB the session is shown as "buffer busy wait". Adding indexes didn't help.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard et al - actually I think the first part of my response is a valid answer because there is nothing intrinsically wrong with the query and the problem is an application one. I agree I am now involved in a dialogue with the OP to get to a fuller diagnosis.

Comment: @APC Sorry, it was by review and because the answer still asks still asks for clarification by OP, it was marked accordingly. You made some edits so will retract. Thanks.

Comment: Select sql given above returns ORA-00937. Only this session reads from MY_TABLE. It is intentional that MY_TABLE is accessed 3 times to get desired result set.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - it's a valid concern because my answer still asks questions. I hope to be able to convert this to a solid answer. Otherwise I'll delete it (assuming the community doesn't zap it fist :D )

Comment: @Dakshitha - I missed out the GROUP BY clause. Please try again

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the data-set now. Will execute this and share once the data is available.

Comment: I have executed it now. But now there are no buffer busy waits. "db file sequential read" is present on the session.

`SELECT p3, count(*) 
  FROM v$session_wait 
  WHERE event='db file sequential read'
GROUP BY p3` gives below result:

P3                     COUNT(*)               
---------------------- ---------------------- 
1                      2

Comment: Sorry but this is a moving target. There's not much we can do to help when things are this vague. What you need is an onsite or dedicated tuning expert who can interactively investigate and diagnose.

Comment: @APC, Worked with our DBA and he disabled the plan directives at system level using. 

alter system set "_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control"=0; 

As per him, SQL plan directives were created as cardinality mis-estimates  after executing the sql.
After that timing was greatly improved and the problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with our DBA and he disabled the plan directives at system level using
`alter system set "_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control"=0;`
As per him, SQL plan directives were created as cardinality mis-estimates after executing the sql. After that timing was greatly improved and the problem is solved.